# Why is my array returning empty?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
var array= ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
var finalArray= array.slice(2,2);
console.log(finalArray);
```

This returns:

```
finalArray=[]
```

I would like it to return:

```
finalArray=["c","d"]
```

Comment: array.slice(0,2) will be the right approach

Comment: [Rubber Duck Debug](https://rubberduckdebugging.com) your code.

Answer (score 6):

The first argument is the index at which to begin extraction, and the second one is the index **before** which to end extraction. So, to get the last two elements (indexes 2 and 3), you need to do this:

```js
var array= ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
var finalArray = array.slice(2, 4); // or slice(2), since 4 is the length of this array

console.log(finalArray);
```

More info on `Array.prototype.slice()` is available in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

Answer (score 1):

Do `slice(2,4)` instead. 
The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from begin to end (end not included). The original array will not be modified.- MDN

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide end index as the second argument in [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method. You are getting an empty array since you are providing both start and end index as same(there are no elements in between).

```js
var array = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
var finalArray = array.slice(2, 4);
console.log(finalArray);
```

**FYI :** In case you want to get whole elements from the start index then ignore the second argument.

```js
var array = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
var finalArray = array.slice(2);
console.log(finalArray);
```

Answer (score -2):

The second index (the end) must be what you want the end to be +1 starting from 0. So if you want element 2 and 3 (always starting from 0) do like this:

```
return array.slice(2, 4);
```